# Call function with Timer in Unreal Engine crash Unreal Engine

Tags: timer, unreal-engine4

I want to disable collisions with an object after I collide with it, for a few seconds. This is the code that I have right now (used code seen online):

```
Other->SetActorEnableCollision(false);

// Restart the collisions after a few seconds
TimerDelegate.BindUFunction(this, FName("RestoreCollision"), Other);
GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(TimerHandle, TimerDelegate, 5.0f, false);
```

This code is inside a notifyHit with this partial signature: `NotifyHit(class UPrimitiveComponent* MyComp, class AActor* Other` (just so you see where this `Other` is coming from.

When I start the collision, it crashes the whole Unreal Engine Editor.

Do you know why? What do I have to change? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing F5 in visual studio to run your Unreal project in debug mode. Unreal Editor crashes are usually caused by triggering a breakpoint in the engine code. The breakpoint tip will show when running in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some time ago. The problem was that I didn’t use the macro “UFUNCTION” on my BindUFunction. I don’t know if that could be your problem. I hope this help you! If not, like the partner told you, try debugging with F5. May could be some access to a nullptr or similar.